# Magento Payment Block Custom Info

Tags: module, blocks, payment, magento-1, additional-information

I want to show "Creation date" of an order in:

```
Sales -> Orders -> User -> Information -> Payment methods
```

At the moment I'm using this code:

```
class Company_Module_Block_Info extends Mage_Payment_Block_Info
{
    protected function _prepareSpecificInformation($transport = null)
    {
        if (null !== $this->_paymentSpecificInformation) {
            return $this->_paymentSpecificInformation;
        }

        $info = $this->getInfo();
        //Zend_Debug::dump($info); //List with created_at date

        $transport = new Varien_Object();
        $transport = parent::_prepareSpecificInformation($transport);
        $transport->addData(array(
            Mage::helper('payment')->__('Expiration date') => $info->getExpireDate(),
            Mage::helper('sales')->__('Creation date') => $info->getCreatedAt(),
            Mage::helper('payment')->__('Picked up by') => $info->getPickupCustomer()
        ));

        return $transport;
    }
}
```

The line which isn't working is this one:

```
Mage::helper('sales')->__('Creation date') => $info->getCreatedAt(),
```

At the moment it gives `NULL`, but I expect to return the custom creation date of the order (in format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss). When I use `Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->getFirstItem(); $order->getCreatedAt();` It returns the first created at date of the first order, but I need it for the selected order.

Does someone have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Could you explain _what_ isn't working? "The line which isn't working is this one". What do you expect it to do? What is happening now? Do you get any errors?

Comment: At the moment it gives NULL, but I expect to return the custom creation date of the order (in format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss). When I use Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->getFirstItem(); 
$order->getCreatedAt(); It returns the first created at date of the first order, but I need it for the selected order. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$info` will hold an instance of `Mage_Payment_Model_Info`  or `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment` (which extends `Mage_Payment_Model_Info`)

The creation date that you want to get is the creation date of the actual sales order, but you are trying to get it from the info model.

If you would call `$info->getOrder()->getCreatedAt()` then that should work.